# Semaphore in KeyUp event handler -- locks keyboard input

Tags: c#, semaphore

**I'm trying to understand Semaphore's**. 
In short, I've placed a "long" running procedure (which accesses Network resources), `InitializeNamesAsync("","","")`, in a `KeyUp event handler`. I'm trying to allow the user to do continuous typing without slowdown while `viewNames` is being initialized by `InitializeNamesAsync()`. Since the user will be continuously typing, the `KeyUp event handler` will be called many times while the `InitializeNamesAsync()` method is running.

While the below code compiles fine, it locks up forever completely stopping keyboard input.

So my questions are:

1. is this an appropriate use of Semaphore's?
2. how can I make this work?
3. Is there a better way?

TIA

Having defined

```
ResourceLock = new Semaphore(0, 1);


private async void _cboLastName_KeyUpAsync(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (viewNames == null)
        {

            ResourceLock.WaitOne();
            await InitializeNamesAsync("", "", "");
            ResourceLock.Release();

        }
   }
```

Comment: Sounds like a case for Reactive Extensions, and debouncing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's fundamental issue with your design, though you are using the `Semaphore` to allow multiple threads to enter and execute the event inside the critical region, but challenge is, **which thread are you blocking?**

As the event is executed on the `Ui thread`, which is just 1 and unique, what's happening is:

- Your code enters the Event, Calls the `WaitOne` for the Semaphore on the Ui Thread and it's done you are blocked, it doesn't even execute the Async method as expected

> Check the out the following Console code, what do you think is the result ?

**Following code leads to Deadlock, since Ui or Main Console Thread is waiting upon itself**

```
async Task Main()
{

    Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0, 2);
    for(int x = 0; x < 5;x++)
    {
        s.WaitOne();
        await Test(x);      
        s.Release();
    }    
}

async Task Test(int x)
{
    $"Entering : {x}".Dump();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

- In above code `await Test(x);` and `s.Release();` are never called

> What are the options, review modified design:

```
async Task Main()
{   
    for(int x = 0; x < 5;x++)
    {
        await Test(x);
        s.WaitOne();
    }   
}

Semaphore s = new Semaphore(0,2);

async Task Test(int x)
{
    $"Entering : {x}".Dump();
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    s.Release();
}
```

> What's different here:

1. Async method was called before the Semaphore `WaitOne` is called
2. Semaphore `Release` happens post the finish of Async method, not on same thread (in this case on threadpool thread)

And you will find this code will execute successfully without any deadlock

> What's the solution:

1. Don't call `WaitOne` on a unique thread like Ui thread, that's a recipe for deadlock, especially when `Release` is also scheduled on same thread
2. Call `Release` on a separate thread (I have used the Async method, which is using Threadpool thread in this case)

> Other Details:

- Ideally Semaphore is meant for the multiple threads to enter the critical region, if you are expecting only one thread, then Sempahore may not be the right choice, but it helps signaling threads unlike lock, you may also review `ManualResetEvent` and `AutoResetEvent`, which supports `Signaling / EventWaitHandle` use cases

Comment: What is confusing me here is that I thought the code after s.WaitOne is protected from multiple entries. How is "Task.Delay(3000)" not hit everytime Test(int x) is called? Thanks. (The order seems wrong to me).

Comment: So -- I got it backwards :)  "Ideally Semaphore is meant for multiple threads to enter the critical region"  -- not keep them out??

Comment: Regarding the first comment, if you are going to wait on a thread and other calls including `Release` are scheduled on same thread, that's a classic case of deadlock, since `Waitone` is meant for the thread calling it, its making it wait and no other call can be scheduled, till the point its released

Comment: Regarding second comment, if you review the Sempahore constructor, it has a parameter related to maximum number of threads allowed in the critical region, thus sort of rationing, it doesn't queue up the threads to move one by one like a lock. Also you may want to review Manual and Auto reset events which support similar use cases, they all wait and signal release

Answer (score 1):

The thread is blocked because you enter it twice and semaphore doesn't allow enter the same thread twice(while e.g. Monitor.Enter allows - but then it is not clear why would you need it here).

As I understand you need to launch initialization in the background.

Since it is UI thread you might not need to use synchronization primitives(in this case, at least, not in general). I think it would be enough just having two variables like

beingInitialized

and initialized with the code like

```
private async void EnsureInitialized()
{

    if(!initialized && !beingInitialized)
   {
    beingInitalized = true;
    await StartInitialization();
    initalized = true;
    beingInitialized = false;
   }
}
```

And call it then as fire and forget

like

```
private async void _cboLastName_KeyUpAsync(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    EnsureInitialized();
    ...
```

Comment: @VictorArsanov  Actually, this is what I initially did--but using a semaphore seemed like a good choice -- and I am still trying to understand the use of a semaphore.

Comment: Well, I think not in the UI thread, because any lock inside the ui thread means there is a chance it will block there for some time, which is not considered good. BTW, why do you use semaphore class, not lock instruction?

Comment: Thanks.  Just trying to understand a new concept for me. I like doing things differently when trying to improve my code :) I had used a lock instruction in the past.

Comment: @ViktorArsanov this is similar to double null pattern check for singleton, where you are relying on a boolean value being set to not reinitialize but this is not good for concurrent scenarios, since its quite likely that more than one thread will enterand will execute the logic more than once which is undesirable. Using the synchronization constructs is always a better choice. For many programming languages, such patterns are broken. Also `EnsureInitialized()` call shall be awaited

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Why always? In case there no parallel execution, why would I use any sync construct? And how EnsureInitialized can be awaited and what for? No, I understand we can change void to task to await, but do we need it here?

Comment: @ViktorArsanov the answer is in context of the OPs question, where there's a multi-threading and Synchronization (as per OPs design) and there this kind of pattern can break, for no parallel execution there's no issue. Regarding `async` all functions shall return a `Task / Task<T>` except events for backward compatibility, and all async function shall be awaited throughout the chain, otherwise the benefits of the async processing are not forthcoming

Comment: @MrinalKamboj So, not always, but depending on context. And why all functions should return task? What if I need fire and forget it?

Comment: @ViktorArsanov how many use cases do you have for "Fire and Forget", a very limited number of use cases and the introduction of the void for async was for the backward compatibility with the events. Using the Task also you can "Fire and Forget", if you don't `await` it, guidelines recommends using Task in every Async method, as that makes methods much more responsible and lot of trailing actions can thus be scheduled